# VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER when setting apiVersion to VK_VERSION_1_0

Tags: c++, vulkan

Trying to set up a Vulkan application but when I set the `apiVersion` to `VK_VERSION_1_0` I get `VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER` from `vkCreateInstance`.
It works normally if I set the `apiVersion = 0`.

Am I missing something or is this behavior unintended (I think I am missing something)?

```
    VkApplicationInfo appInfo;
    appInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_APPLICATION_INFO;
    appInfo.pNext = NULL;
    appInfo.pApplicationName = "Vulkan Tutorial";
    appInfo.applicationVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
    appInfo.pEngineName = "LUL";
    appInfo.engineVersion = VK_MAKE_VERSION(0, 0, 0);
    appInfo.apiVersion = VK_VERSION_1_0;

  VkResult result = vkCreateInstance(&instanceInfo, NULL, &instance);

    if (result != VK_SUCCESS){
        __debugbreak();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using the wrong macro!
Use `VK_API_VERSION_1_0` instead.

(`VK_VERSION_1_0` is just to detect you included 1.0 header of Vulkan. It does have only `True` as the value. )

(BTW It is optional to use `VkApplicationInfo`. If you do use it it is optional to provide app and/or engine name. App and Engine does not necessarily use Vulkan's versioning scheme, so it does not necessarily make sense to use `VK_MAKE_VERSION` there)